# Excel VBA select entire sheet using Range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using the following code to search through a sheet to find out how many times does the word 'example' appear.

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A10"), "example")
```

I can't seem to figure out how to iterate through the entire sheet using the Range function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below to look for string "example" in entire sheet.

`Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, "example")`

**using wildcards**

`Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells, "*example*")`

Comment: @user2946105 It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to iterate through the entire sheet? You can just change the extend the range?

A1:A10

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A10"), "example")
```

A1:E10

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:E10"), "example")
```

Entire sheet

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Cells, "example")
```